# Функция Fact2(N)

Tags: c++builder

Задача. Описать функцию Fact2(N) вещественного типа, вычисляющую двойной факториал: N!! = 135... N, если N - нечетное; N!! = 246... N, если N - четное (N > 0 - параметр целого типа; вещественное возращаемое значение используется для того, чтобы избежать целлочисленного переполнения при больших значениях N). С помощью этой функции найти двойные факториалы пяти данных целых чисел.

```
#include <iostream.h>

double Fact2(int n);

{
    double p = 1;
    int j;

    for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        if ((n % 2 == 0) && (j % 2 == 0))
            p = p * (double) j;
        if ((n % 2 != 0) && (j % 2 != 0))
            p = p * (double) j;
    }
    return p;
}

void main()
{

    int n;

    cout << " Enter number " << " ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Fact2(" << n << ")=" << Fact2(n) << endl;

}
```

Comment: Ошибку выдает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double Fact2(int n) // Зачем тут ';' была? Оттуда и ошибка
// А вообще алгоритм проще
{
   double p = 1;
   while (n > 0)
   {
      p = p * (double)n;
      n -= 2;
   }
   return p;
}
```

Comment: вторую часть заменила вот так:
 
int main()
{
    int n;

    while (printf("enter n: ") && scanf("%d", &n)
        && n && printf("%.0f\n", Fact2(n)));
    return 0;
}